# DataMatrix ECC 200 (ISO/IEC 16022) barcode component needed for Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, barcode, reportbuilder

I'm looking for a 2D barcode component for Delphi 2009 with support for the **DataMatrix ECC 200** symbology (ISO/IEC 16022). I do require the source code of the component to be available (free or commercial) and it has to work with ReportBuilder.

Does anyone out there have a suitable solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I have created a wrapper for a previous version of [dmtx](http://www.libdmtx.org/) that reads and writes barcodes. The wrapper has since been removed from the dmtx wiki. I have now made it available on https://github.com/JanOosting/delphidmtx

Comment: Thank you for your response! This seems to fit the requirements nicely. I will take a look at the wrapper. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Han Soft](http://www.han-soft.com/barcode2d.php).

[TBarcode2D_DataMatrixECC200](http://www.han-soft.com/releases/barcode2d/documents/b_datamatrixecc200.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately Han Soft does not include the source code for the 2D barcode component (I checked with the developer) so the search continues...

Answer (score 0):

After extensive research I've settled with Barcode Studio, which comes with full source and has support for ReportBuilder:

http://www.barcode-software.eu/studio

Thanks to all who answered :)

Comment: How did this work? I asked for a refund because I couldn't make it work for FastReport and they never answered any of my questions.